# Exchange Online - Emails undelivered due to full mailbox

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

By accident we had downgraded a user that had >80GB of email down to Microsoft 365 standard with a limit of 50GB.

No emails could be sent or recieved for the user, until now when we upgraded the license to Exchange 2.

However, the issue is that the emails from when the mailbox was full and until we set the license have not been delievered. How can I "resend" them or force Exchange to do it?

Answer (score 2):

They won't be delivered. Exchange rejects messages when the mailbox size limit is reached.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#capacity-alerts

Comment: All such mail was already bounced. Only the original sender can "resend" it.

Answer (score 0):

As joeqwertty has said above, these messages have been rejected to deliver, the sender has the option to try resending the mail later. To receive messages again, the user must delete email until the mailbox is below the size limit. For more details: [Office 365 - Unable to send/receive messages due to mailbox quota](https://kb.wisc.edu/office365/page.php?id=91248)

Comment: Got it, I feel that if you've done this it should Prohibit Send, and not prohibit recieve right away. If the user can't send emails then the admin at least has a chance to correct the issue before any emails are "missed"... :(

Comment: If you read the article linked in my answer, you'll see that it does prohibit send first, as well as issuing a warning to the user.

Comment: You can only ask the original sender to resend.